# No data when emitting event NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I try to fire an event with some data with it.
The data is an object with 3 large arrays of numbers.
I want to reset those arrays, after I fired the event.
When I do that, the event listener is not getting the data.

How is that?

Works:

```
    // Assume each array filled with alot of data
    let collected_data: collected_data = {
        battery_data: [], 
        sensor_data: [],
        time_data: []
    }
    sensorData.emit("data", collected_data);
```

Not working:

```
    let collected_data: collected_data = {
        battery_data: [],
        sensor_data: [],
        time_data: []
    }
    sensorData.emit("data", collected_data);
    
    collected_data.battery_data = [];
    collected_data.sensor_data= [];
    collected_data.time_data= [];
```

Comment: where is listener ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this syntax:

```
let collected_data = {
        battery_data: [], 
        sensor_data: [],
        time_data: []
    }
```

Comment: Im using typescript.

Comment: So? This is valid Typescript

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to events coordination, as far as I understand you want to `emit` an event `then` after the emission you want to empty your arrays.

I'd suggest you add another event for cleaning data (e.g `clean_data`) and when the receiver receive your data it emits this event, and you have a listener that listen for that event to empty your data accordingly, then start structuring your code based on events and consider every possible scenario before you fully trust the code as it might be harder to coordinate some code paths.

Comment: I am assuming `sensorData.emit("data", collected_data);` is synchronous. I dont understand why the listener dont get the data, even though the event with the data is fired before I clean the arrays. - `collected_data` is not a global variable